# do_rootfs error due to package installation

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm writing my own Distro layer (as well as my own image recipe) but I keep getting this error when I try to build an image:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packagegroup-base-extended : Depends: packagegroup-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are including your packagegroups into your image recipe instead of distro configuration.

For example:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/meta-my-distro/conf/distro/include/my-distro-base.inc b/meta-my-distro/conf/distro/include/my-distro-base.inc
index f4dba77..36ca349 100644
--- a/meta-my-distro/conf/distro/include/my-distro-base.inc
+++ b/meta-my-distro/conf/distro/include/my-distro-base.inc
@@ -15,13 +15,6 @@ 

-DISTRO_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "\
-                          packagegroup-my-distro-misc \
-"

diff --git a/meta-my-distro/recipes-core/images/my-distro-image-base.bb b/meta-my-distro/recipes-core/images/my-distro-image-base.bb
index c896c6c..f83853d 100644
--- a/meta-my-distro/recipes-core/images/my-distro-image-base.bb
+++ b/meta-my-distro/recipes-core/images/my-distro-image-base.bb
@@ -11,5 +11,12 @@ 

+IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "\
+                          packagegroup-my-distro-misc \
+"
```